# Current flood situation going on in Alicante (Spain) and Valencia (Spain) September 2019

Tags: spain, natural-disasters, valencia

I am travelling to Alicante and Valencia for 2 weeks from 20th September. How is the flood situation in Alicante and Valencia, should that be a matter of concern for tourists and travellers?

Comment: Difficult to answer since the effects are localised. Perhaps this link https://elpais.com/politica/2019/09/14/actualidad/1568479258_878736.html#?ref=rss&format=simple&link=guid may help you. It is, not surprisingly, in Spanish but a translation service on-line should help you.

Comment: A friend currently in Valencia (city center, nearby beaches) has had no issues with flooding, and didn't even know it was happening until seeing posts online, so I imagine it is not going to be an issue if you stay within the centre.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, unless you are heading to Orihuela-Murcia area. If you are going to stay in Alicante city and Valencia city you won't have any problem. The floods have affected mostly to the south of Alicante province (with a lot of problems in roads and highways) but no problem in the Alicante-Valencia highway. Additionally, in two weeks you won't find any trace of the floodings.